# Losing closing img tag with jQuery's .html() method

Tags: jquery, image

I'm using the jQuery `.html()` method to add images to a div in my webpage dynamically when I user clicks on the event that image belongs too.

I've confirmed that the image tag is properly formatted when returned to the server, but once inserted using `.html()`, the ending portion of the tag is lost.

For example, what was originally

```
<img src="poop.txt"></img>
```

Comes out as being

```
<img src="poop.txt">
```

on the actual webpage. What is the cause of this? `.html()` works perfectly with a set of spans that I'm inserting in a similar fashion on another page on the site, but when it comes to image tags, it fails.

Comment: Could you not return the image tag as `<img src="poop.txt" />` instead?

Comment: That's just what the browser turns an img tag into, `<img src=".." />` would be converted into the same. It's the internal representation the browser works with, you cannot do anything about that. And I cannot think of a situation where this would be an actual issue!?

Comment: @Niko Yes, I just changed my code to do that, and it still strips the closing portion of the image tag. How do I get around the "/>" being stripped?

Comment: @Ezra_Bender You changed your code so that it does what? Output `<img />` instead? What I was trying to say: The browser strips the closing portion from that as well, that's just how it works (actually, some browsers might not do that, or something completely different, it's really an implementation detail). Nothing you should need to care about in any situation.

Comment: @Niko yep, that's what I meant- I changed the output so that I got <img src="example.jpg" />, however, like you said, that gets stripped as well. Is there a best practice/standard method for inserting img nodes into a webpage?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem: All the methods you tried actually work, you will see an image. I'd recommend using whatever would be valid with the specified doctype, e.g. if you're using a XHTML doctype, use `<img src=".." />` and let the browser do with it whatever it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (actually it's a safe-guard and a benefit) is that JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, creates only *valid* HTML. As the `img` tag has no closing tag (since it can't have any content, it self-closes) it isn't appended to the web-page.

References:

- [`img` element, Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/img).

Comment: But even with <img src="blah.jpg" />, the closing portion is stripped from the tag. Is there a proper way to get around this?

Comment: Not really, no; if you think of the HTML as a... *hint* to the browser as to how to construct the DOM, the browser doesn't need the closing `/` to know it's an empty element, so it's discarded as unnecessary. At least that's my rationalisation of what happens. It may, or may not, be anywhere near correct. =/

Comment: So is there no way to actually insert an img element into a page using .html? I know this shouldn't be that difficult of a problem, but I'm having a hard time of figuring out an alternative way to insert an element.

Comment: You can insert the element, yes; but you won't get the closing slash in the element tag.

Comment: @Ezra_Bender It doesn't matter how you insert `<img>` element (with `/` or without). Browser will do all the job for you. You should only consider that by the standards `<img>` element could not have any child elements inside, hence it should not have closing `</img>` tag.

Comment: @DavidThomas gotcha. How does one close the element though?

Comment: It self-closes. You don't need to close it, except (I think) in XHTML, where the `<img />` is mandatory, but in regular HTML just `<img>` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Image tag `img` does not have a closing tag. When JQuery creates new element it does it in valid way.

Reference:

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img

Answer (score 0):

Jquery creates valid html code. `</img>` does not exist in the html standard.